# "and" for single subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have those documents:

```
{
    "result": "ok",
    "variants": [
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": false,
                "state2": false
            }
        },
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": false,
                "state2": false
            }
        }

    ]
}

{
    "result": "ok",
    "variants": [
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": false,
                "state2": false
            }
        },
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": false,
                "state2": true
            }
        }

    ]
}


{
    "result": "not_ok",
    "variants": [
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": true,
                "state2": false
            }
        },
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": true,
                "state2": false
            }
        }

    ]
}


{
    "result": "not_ok",
    "variants": [
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": true,
                "state2": false
            }
        },
        {
            "state": {
                "state1": false,
                "state2": true
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

and i nead to find those one where at least one variant in the document has `state1: false` and `state2: false`. I have tried this find:

```
{
    "variants.state.state1": false,
    "variants.state.state2": false
}
```

But it gives me the documents where one of the variants has `state1: false` and one of the variants has `state2: false`. It applies the where to the subdocuments individually and not both filters to one subdocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer:

```
{
    "variants.state": { "$elemMatch" : {"state1" : false, "state2" : false } }
}
```